# How to realize sum(field) group by multi field in elasticsearch?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm using logstash to save row data from MySQL to ElasticSearch. How to calculate sum on one field group by two fields?

For example, here is one table named "Students", it has several columns: id, class_id, name, gender, age;
and here is one SQL query:

```sql
select class_id, gender, sum(age) from Students group by class_id, gender;
```

How to translate this SQL to ElasticSearch high level rest client API call?
Below is my try, but it is not correct:

```java
public TermsAggregationBuilder constructAggregation() {
    TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_classid")
            .field("classId.keyword");
    aggregation = aggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_gender").field("gender.keyword"));
    aggregation = aggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_age")
            .field("age"));
    return aggregation;
  }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting and also please add mappings

Answer (score 0):

Following is the raw query for your sql statement

```
POST aggregation_index_2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "gender_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "class_id_aggregator": {
          "terms": {
         "aggs": {
              "field": "class_id"
          },
           "age_sum_aggregator": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "age"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Mappings**

```
PUT aggregation_index_2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "gender": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "class_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in es version 6.3.2 ,it will raise error like below:{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "[terms] unknown field [aggs], parser not found"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[terms] unknown field [aggs], parser not found"
  },
  "status": 400
}